# WPF Unhandled-Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

I have a .NET 4.6 application running on Windows 8.1. The way I currently delivering the application to the remote client is by copying all the content from my `bin\release` folder to a designated folder at the remote PC.
I've registered to both `App_DispatcherUnhandledException` and `CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException` events in order to be able to log any unhandeled exceptions that might occur:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    //In App.xaml
    public App()
    {
        DispatcherUnhandledException += App_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
    }

    private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (ex != null)
            ex.LogException();
    }

    private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Exception.LogException();
    }
}
```

`LogException()` just writes the `ToString()` of the exception to a text file:

```
public static string LogException(this Exception ex)
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Log.txt", Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
}
```

My problem is that whenever I run the app on the remote machine it doesn't start, no Windows message about an unhandeled exception are displayed and the process exists in the task manager.
Is there any way to figure out what is causing this behavior?

**EDIT:**
So apparently this had something to do with a corrupted or missing windows update. I did a system restore on the PC and reinstalled .NET 4.6 and its corresponding updates and it solved the problem. I had no luck finding informative details in the event log.

Comment: How are you starting the app on the remote machine ?

Comment: by double clicking the .exe file (the startup project output in my solution)

Comment: The first thing I would check is the (Windows) Event Viewer. Search for errors in the application events. There's often one with a stacktrace in there.

Comment: Do you have any dependencies for your assembly?

Comment: Yes, all the .dll files exists in the folder and the same app does run on my dev PC when running from this folder

Comment: it doesnt mean it had error so dont wait for an exeption, what kind of app it is? Probably app needs some kind of dependencies.

Comment: What if your exception handling/log writing code is broken?

Comment: @MustafaEkici what exacly do you mean by "what kind of app it is"?

Comment: what that application does? Use any low level processes or something like that?

Comment: @MustafaEkici it does use a `DllImport` but doesn't an exception of that type should be caught?

Comment: yeah that is, try to install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages

Comment: @PieterWitvoet good idea, I will try that

Comment: I would check the permissions. Is the user having the right permission to write to the specified log file? Try run the application as an administrator.

Comment: Silly question, but do you actually have 4.6 installed on the remote machine?

Comment: Generally, application failures will be recorded in the Windows event log. Check using Event Viewer. Note that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem on other people's computers, this question is likely to be impossible to answer as stated, and not on-topic.